# jQuery - Bootstrap Datepicker onChange issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying change link when a date is selected but whenever I select a date, I get
`?day=` Here's my code:

Markup:

`<i class="icon-calendar"></i>`

It only works when I use input
`<input type="text" class="datepicker">`

Javascript:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
                endDate: "-2d"
            })

            .on('changeDate', function(ev){
                var dateData = $('.datepicker').val();
                window.location.href = "?day=" + dateData ;
            });
        });
```

Expected results: `?day=2013-11-01`

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [`documentation`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate) you can get the formatted date with the `format()` function accessible through the event object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            endDate: "-2d"
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(ev){
            window.location.href = "?day=" + ev.format();
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can access the date via `ev`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        endDate: "-2d"
    })

    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        var dateData = new Date(ev.date);  // this is the change
        window.location.href = "?day=" + dateData ;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but I think it should be more like

```
$(".datepicker").on('change', function(ev){
    var dateData = $(this).val();
    window.location.href = "?day=" + dateData ;
});
```